# Calculate output nodes (consumer acceptance) of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, intercept

[image: Neutal network illustration]

**To make it a bit easier I am using round numbers (integers) in this example.**

We have to calculate the value for consumer acceptance. Therefore we have the following input variables (fat = 3; salt = 2). The transformation function used is *g(x) = 3x*.

[image: Neural network including weights]

The weights (e.g. -3, 2; -2) and biases are displayed in the scheme above. The correct outcome (consumer acceptance) value for this assignment is 57. However, I don't need how to get there.

**My current calculation (equals 63):**

g(-2 + ((3 * -3) + (2 * 2))) = -7 (x, 3x = -21)

g(-1 + ((3 * -2) + (2 * 3))) = -1 (x, 3x = -3)

g( 1 + ((3 * 2) + (2 * -2))) =  3 (x, 3x = 9)

g( 1 + (-21 * -1)) = 22 (x, 3x = 66)

g( 1 + (-3 * -2)) = 7 (x, 3x = 21)

g( 1 + ( 9 * -1)) = -8 (x, 3x = -24)

**Total: 66 + 21 - 24 = 63**

Who is able to help me out?

Comment: You appear to have added the final bias of $1$ three times rather than once, thereby making your result twice $3\times 1$, or $6$, too high.